# Calculations / Accessing Vectors using Parallel Programming C++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, parallel-processing

I have a matrix:

```
std::vector<std::vector<double> >* p_mat_cache = 
    new std::vector<std::vector<double> >(3, std::vector<double>());
```

and a vector:

```
std::vector<double>* p_val_vec_1 = new std::vector<double>(*mpStages);
```

where 'mpStages' is an int value. At a point I apply a function where the following occurs:

```
pMatCache->at(1).push_back((*pValVec1)[j+1]);
pMatCache->at(2).push_back((*pValVec1)[j]);

(*pValVec2)[j] = fmax(*mpK - CalculateS(i, j), *mpD *(0.5 * (*pValVec1)[j+1] +
                      0.5*(*pValVec1)[j]));

pMatCache->at(0).push_back((*pValVec2)[j]);
```

pValVec1 and pMatCache correspond to the local names. pValVec2 is another vector of length 'mpStages-1'. 'CalculateS' is as below:

```
double AbstractOptionSolver::CalculateS(int n, int i)
{
    return pow(*mpUp,i) * pow(*mpDown, n-i) * *mpS;
}
```

where private variables '*mpS', '*mpUp' and '*mpDown' do not change during the implementation of the code. What I am trying to do is run a part of this in parallel that I assume can be done as below:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    pMatCache->at(1).push_back((*pValVec1)[j+1]);
    pMatCache->at(2).push_back((*pValVec1)[j]);

    (*pValVec2)[j] = fmax(*mpK - CalculateS(i, j), *mpD *(0.5 * (*pValVec1)[j+1] +
                          0.5*(*pValVec1)[j]));
}

pMatCache->at(0).push_back((*pValVec2)[j]);
```

However this code keeps crashing due to addition of 'omp parallel' even when I just have the omp parallel including only the push backs. Was wondering if anybody had any idea why this is happening?

I'm also trying to further understand parallel programming to know when/when I can't use it in/on a function given sometimes making certain aspects parallel has caused this code to crash for unknown reasons. Would be great if anyone had any sources to help me out with regards to that as well.

Comment: race condition here

Comment: even when I'm just applying push backs in two different locations of the matrix @appleapple ?

Answer (score 0):

First, #pragma omp parallel will only spawn a bunch of threads at that point that will do the exact same operations in the scoped portion, it will not assign a unique j or i per thread.  You may want to look at http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#ParallelismConditionalityClauseIf to see how to parallelize based on index.  But given the code snippets its hard to tell exactly what you want to do.

The next biggest issue is that you would have multiple threads calling .push_back simultaneously.  You'd need to preallocate and assign the values instead.

I'm not sure why you are using pointers and new syntax with std::vector.  Usually one uses vector with RAII and avoid new/delete calls.

Comment: I've provided what I want to do in the question with the two differing pieces of code showing where I am and what I'm trying to perceptually achieve. I will have a look at the link to though to see if it gives me a better insight.

Additionally I use new syntax because of the idea that the vectors lay in a method that are part of an object which may not be deleted, but be edited with the method being repeated thousands to hundreds of thousands of times. As such I'll come across allocation errors establishing vectors without the new/delete syntax

Comment: Mainly I'm confused by the snippet with the #pragma omp parallel part.  From what you've posted, it looks like you're trying to parallelize individual push_back statements, which will not work.  However, you should be able to parallelize your code overall if you have threads do more and preallocate your buffers, but its impossible to tell without knowing what's happening outside the snippets you've posted.

Comment: I'm trying to parallelize the push backs and the vector calculation, for which all info is known, and there's no overlap in read/writes. Does it just simply not work? Or is there a reason for it not working? If I have to pre-allocate and then assign values, then given I don't know how many columns there will be in this matrix there's surely no point to trying to attempt to parallelize this part? To show you what's going on outside this function is impossible in this forum given it's part of a large project with several interacting classes. It'd be a huge chunk of code to show.

Comment: Late reply, but based on what you've written your best bet for an immediate performance gain is to use the vector reserve function.

Comment: The push-backs are not parallelizable since it reallocates the memory of the vector each time it exceeds the reserved heap size.  The internal pointer may change every time it is invoked, so each thread may end up with a different memory pointer, since stl container changes are non in general thread safe.  This is also a reason you may be getting a performance hit in that code, every push_back causing a vector reallocation.  Using reserve in large chunks will help.  As for parallelizing, if you have no information about the new possible columns I don't see an easy way to parallelize.

Answer (score 0):

When doing parallel programming you MUST be aware of "locking data". This technic prevents two (or more) threads to modify simultaneously the same data, corrupting it.

Comment: Parallel for loops modifying data within the same vector/matrix have worked for me. Why would it applying locking outside of this?

Comment: Instead of theoryzing I'd try setting locks, so as to check if locking solves the crash.

Comment: Will try it out. Appreciate the help.